MS Graph API : How to get contact list groups
In the outlook, there is a contact list like bellow image.
I know I how to get contacts using graph api such as
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$count=true

However, is there a way to access contact list using Microsoft graph api? I know there is post for same question, but it's 7 years ago (Microsoft API for contact list groups like those in OWA)


Still not supported

still? 7 years and no update lol

This feature is still not supported. You can vote for it here:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/de785de3-c488-ee11-a81c-0022484e5453
